# Package 'grub-pc' has no installation candidate

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I'm trying to make a dual boot with Windows/Ubuntu, but after I installed Ubuntu I can't boot from USB anymore!

I'm trying to use Boot-Repair, but the problem is it asks me to run a command that refers to a package with no installation candidate!

Here is the command with the error:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux-generic
Package 'grub-pc' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Is Internet working, Boot-Repair is running a command to download new packages from Repository, so it can reinstall it. Also are you booting in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. If UEFI you should be using grub-efi-amd64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

Only closed and opened again the boot-repair, choose different repair options on advanced, followed the steps and Vualá!

Done. Now i can dual boot.

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: can you provide what option you choose on advanced option?